# Cannot Ping Devices connected to powerline when RE200 is on the powerline network

Tags: home-networking, ping, wireless-access-point, powerline-networking

I am a proud owner of TP-Link Products and things are going well regarding everything except with something regarding this configuration.

When the RE200 is connected to the network, Devices connected to the VR600 wireless cannot ping any other devices connected to the Powerline Adapter. For Example Smartphones 1 / 2 cannot ping Desktop PC / WebOS TVs and vice versa.
However Deskop PC can ping WebOS TVs without any problem as well as the RE200 and its wirelessly connected devices.

If Smartphone 1 / 2 is connected to RE200 wirelessly, all the WebOS and other devices can be pinged.

If I removed the RE200 and rebooted the VR600. All the devices connected can ping each other, but as soon as the RE200 is connected, it is just a matter of minutes and the previous problem begins to occur.

Is the problem from the VR600 or the switches? I replaced both TL-PA powerline adapters with a very long LAN cable just for testing and the problem is still existant. (Eliminating TL-WPA from the network)

**Full Network View**
[image: Full Network View]

**Simplier View with IPs**
[image: Simpler View with IPs]

Comment: This sounds very much like your RE200 is running a DHCP server which is conflicting with the the VR600.  Check what IP addresses and netmaskes the devices on either side of the network get, and if the devices are both running DHCP servers, disable the one on the RE200

Comment: @davidgo. I suspected that the RE200 is running the DHCP Server. But it is said the DHCP Server is off. It is running on 192.168.1.2 with subnet 255.255.255.0 as the VR600. All the connect devices to the RE200 are 192.168.1.x IPs. If I connected Smartphone 1/2 to RE200, they get the same IPs as they are connected to VR600 Wifi directly.

Comment: Whats the black thing in the middle? a switch? is it layer 2 or layer 3? is it managed/smart etc.? can you add the IP address of each device? did you try to remove components so you can run a test with as few devices as possible? Sounds like some kind of conflict/collision... might there be any connected devices unkown? what about virtual nics on the pc/laptop etc.? also do a ip scan without the M200.

Comment: @Albin. Both Switches are unmanned. The black one is 5 Gigabit ports , while the white one is 5 10/100 Mbps ports. I noticed that the 192.168.1.105 device is not listed on the VR600 client's list. I tried the whole network without the RE200 and things seem to be ok as long as it is not connected. Even after connecting and disconnecting it, things remain the same until I reboot the VR600. I tried replacing the RE200 with another VR600 I have in Router Mode with DHCP Disabled. Lets call it VR600AP. When I tried to connect to VR600AP, the device failed to obtain an IP address.

Comment: I have lots of Virtual Nics on my PC. Didn't check the laptop yet. I did an IP scan with Angry IP Scanner without connecting the RE200. All devices are familiar.All can be pinged if online. When I connect the RE200. The problem occurs. A very strange thing is when I tried Advanced IP Scanner, I was able to find the whole network devices, 192.168.1.101 was ping-able in case of no RE200 attached, but unreachable when RE200 is connected. It was detected in both scenarios though. All the tests above was conducted without any devices connected to the RE200

Comment: On first impulse it sounds like some kind of conflict/collision (or a bad device). You can replace the powerline via Ethernet cable and nothing changes, right (I would remove that from your "simpler view"? What happens if you connect the RE200 to the other two switches/routers? The ping problems only apply to the devices connected via WLAN to the VR600, right? Do you have s.th. you can connect to the VR600 via cable?

Comment: `192.168.1.105 device is not listed on the VR600 client's list` which is correct since 105 is connected to the RE200.

Comment: On first impulse it sounds like some kind of conflict/collision (or a bad device). You can replace the powerline via Ethernet cable and nothing changes, right (I would remove that from your "simpler view"? What happens if you connect the RE200 to the other two switches/routers? The ping problems only apply to the devices connected via WLAN to the VR600, right? Do you have s.th. you can connect to the VR600 via cable? I would try to get the problem further down to as few devices as possible this will make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: Doing more testing. One wireless device (192.168.1.101 / SmartPhone 1) and one LAN wired device (LAN1 Port on the VR600) (192.168.1.107 / PC). Everything is fine. No problems. Now. I added the RE200 to LAN2 Port on the VR600 with Dynamic IP. The VR600 assigned 192.168.1.100 to it. Everything is ok, UNTIL, I connected Smartphone 1 to it. If it is connected to the RE200, the PC can ping it, but once I switch it back to the VR600 wireless, It is no longer reachable. 2 more devices are added to the network, 192.168.103 / Laptop and 192.168.1.104 / Smartphone 3.

Comment: Laptop is connected to RE200, while Smartphone 3 is connected to VR600. Smartphone 1 can ping Smartphone 3, but cannot ping any other devices. PC can ping Laptop but nothing else. It is like the LAN Interface is split from the WLAN interface. No powerline adapters are there in the process.